# Zend framework 2 dynamic routing

Tags: zend-framework2, zend-route

I  want to write routes for this type of urls

```
http://www.example.com/category/sub-category/id.html
```

here category is dynamic. means- i have 100 of categories in my db.
sub category is also dynamic.
i need to show page based on id value.
Any one please suggest.

Comment: I suggest to first read [ZF2Docs: Routing and Controllers](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user-guide/routing-and-controllers.html) and then for more details [ZF2Docs: Zend Mvc Routing](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.mvc.routing.html). Then you come back with what you have tried and we'll help you out ;)

Comment: For this kind of thing I would be tempted to extend one of the available routers to make a custom router to check your db / use caching

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try reading the docs first its very simple :

```
'sample' => array(
                'type' => 'Segment',
                'options' => array(
                    'route' => '/:category[/:sub_category[/:id]].html',
                    'defaults' => array(
                        'controller' => 'Your Controller',
                        'action' => 'Your Action',
                    ),
                ),
            ),
```

With this router config you can have :

```
http://www.example.com/category.html
http://www.example.com/category/sub-category.html
http://www.example.com/category/sub-category/id.html
```